# setLayoutManager in kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How can I define the layoutmanager for RecycleView using kotlin? The code below does not suggest errors, but it is not executing the mentioned part.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    var myAdapter: MyAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView_tweets as RecyclerView?
        mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this) //create recyclerView in LinearLayoutManager


        myAdapter = MyAdapter(this, getMyList())
        mRecyclerView?.adapter = myAdapter

    }

    private fun getMyList(): ArrayList<Tweet>? {
        val tweets: ArrayList<Tweet> = ArrayList()

        val t = Tweet()
        t.name = "John"
        t.tweet = "Things and more things"
        tweets.add(t)

        return tweets
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Vertical or horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I want vertical scrolling

Comment: You're using safe null cast `mRecyclerView?` everywhere so if your mRecyclerView fails to assign (it's not in `R.layout.activity_main` perhaps?) you won't get any errors.

Answer (score 2):

**For Linear Layout manager**

`mRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)`

**For Grid Layout manager**

`mRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define on this way in your xml file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" >
```

And also you have used programetically this way:-

```
mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal,false)
```